# How to detect return from UIApplication openURL

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I'm creating an app using CoreLocation.

Usually, everyone check if CLAuthorizationStatus.
But I wonder if the user disabled LocationService itself on iOS device's Setting, what will happen. And I found that in such case, CLAuthorizationStatus is set to kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied.

So, I think to check the status of Setting, and if location service is disabled, open iOS's Setting like below.

```
if(![CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
{
    UIAlertController *alert = nil;
    alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil
                                                message:@"Please turn on Location Service on iOS's Setting."
                                                preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    [alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                                              style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
                                                  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES"];
                                                  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
                                              }]];
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

It worked fine to open Setting->Privacy->LocationService.

When user turned on LocationService and tap on "return to myApp", how can I detect retuning to myApp from Setting in myApp?

I need to detect as I need to check if user turned on LocationService or not, and if yes, I should try `[locManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];`.

My main question is that "How to detect returning to myApp from the app I opened by `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];`.

Thank you so much for your kind helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot specifically detect that the user has "returned from the app I opened". You can detect that your app has become active, but you cannot know *why* or what the user was doing in the meantime. But you don't need to.

If you simply want to know whether the user turned location services off or on, or otherwise altered your authorization, simply implement the CLLocationManagerDelegate method `locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:`. If the user made a change while the app was suspended, you'll be called as soon as the app is activated again. You should be using this method *anyway* as part of your authorization request structure.

Comment: See my book code for an example where I send the user to Settings to turn on authorization and am ready to start my task if we have authorization when the user returns: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch22p773location/ch35p1032location/ViewController.swift

Comment: Thanks so much, matt!

It worked fine! Thanks for quick replying and sample code!